why do I get FeeTooSmallUTxO everytime?
was trying to get the example of the Stable Coin in the Plutus Pionner Program
I'm constantly getting this error in different parts of the code, NFT minting, deploy contracts, minting coins, right after I sign the transaction:
"{"contents":{"contents":{"contents":{"era":"ShelleyBasedEraConway","error":["ConwayUtxowFailure (UtxoFailure (FeeTooSmallUTxO (Coin 454025) (Coin 393334)))"],"kind":"ShelleyTxValidationError"},"tag":"TxValidationErrorInCardanoMode"},"tag":"TxCmdTxSubmitValidationError"},"tag":"TxSubmitFail"}"
Some say this FeeTooSmallUTxO problem is happening since the Conway hardfork, and it is possible to bypass it with Cardano CLI from what I heard, but not with Lucid, or haven't found a way since is supposed to be done automatically by Lucid. Must also add, I have more than enough balance in the wallet to fulfill the transaction
some other say that the program calculates a fee for the transaction but then adds some other ... stuff on top after?... , which raises the actual fee over the calculated, but I don't see anything reflected on the result of my transaction
Also oddly enough, when I try to replicate this stablecoin example multiple times (because try to test a new version trying to fix the issue) after some tries, my designated oracle wallet doesn't let me burn NFT's anymore by throwing me this error too, for which I have to create a new wallet and then it will work on this new wallet, oddly. I'm using the preview testnet. The more a wallet creates transactions the more fees it will be charged...?
Also I've seen similar issues popping up in other off chain frameworks like MeshJS, and they all mention this issue happening since the Conway hardfork, wonder if that has something to do
